# Flutter: GeoFire library search queryAtLocation not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, geofire

I am testing the Flutter Library https://github.com/bramvbilsen/Flutter-GeoFire.
When I load the example/main.dart file from the library (pointing it to my Firebase) the setLocation() method works (the entry writes to my FirebaseDB) but not the read location or query At Location methods.

[image: Result From save location to FirebaseDB]

// Methods from library example not working..

```
  void getAndPrintLocation() {
    geofire.getLocation("Mechelen", new LocationCallBack(
            (String key, List<double> location) {
          print("Successfully received location!");
          print(key + ": " + location.toString());
        },
            (DatabaseError error) {
          print("Error receiving location!");
          print(error.toString());
        }
    ));
  }

  void createQuery(List<double> location, double radius) {
    this.query = geofire.queryAtLocation(location, radius);
    print(this.query.toString());
  }
```

The return message from queryAtLocaion

```
I/flutter (18068): GeoQuery
I/flutter (18068): --- Center: [51.0259, 4.4775]
I/flutter (18068): --- Radius: 450.0
```

What am I missing.  I am simply trying to get the keys from the queryAtLocaion(location, radius)

Comment: I do not understand. Could you please elaborate on what you are expecting?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I am expecting the printLocation method to return the key or an error...I get nothing in the log.  I am also expecting (but could be wrong) the queryAtLocation to return the whole object from the FirebaseDB at the very least the keys if not the whole object ? Is that wrong ?

Comment: I unfortunately do not have the time to further support this plugin. It was last tested by me way back when Flutter was in its alpha stages, so things might be broken. Pull requests are welcome if you do find issues.

Comment: Hey! I face the same issue as you. What did you do next ?